# Why is this proof valid only in the discrete case?

Tags: statistics

I'm talking about the second proof of the Fisher-Neyman factorisaton theorem given by Wikipedia in this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Fisher%E2%80%93Neyman_factorization_theorem

It says it's valid only in the discrete case, but I don't really understand why. It may be because of one of the following:

- The joint pdf cannot be factorised in the product of the marginal and the conditioned (this is true in the discrete case, but I'm not sure in others)
- The sum $\sum_{x:T(x)= t} f_\theta(x,t)$ may not make sense if the set is not denumerable, but ¿ couldn't we just change it to an integral in the continuous case?

Comment: why aren't there any answers? Shall I clear out something?